# configuring Route.Config to call aspx page with query string in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to call a aspx page from MVC with the below routing.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            null,
            "Operations/BankHolidays.aspx/page{page}",
            new { Controller = "BankHoliday", action = "Index", page = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I want an url like
 **https://localhost:44322/Operations/BankHolidays.aspx?page=2** but I am getting a url like
https://localhost:44322/Operations/BankHolidays.aspx/page2

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Remove `/page{page}` from the route definition and it will be added as a query string rather than a route value.

Comment: That work, but I want to redirect to https://localhost:44322/Operations/BankHolidays.aspx?page=2 and not https://localhost:44322/BankHoliday?page=2

Comment: What is the method and controller name you want to redirect to? I suspect you want `new { Controller = "Operations", action = "BankHoliday" }` (and why do you have a `.aspx` in the route?)

Comment: Actually I am calling a aspx page which calls a controller. My web form page is Operations/BankHolidays.aspx, controller name is BankHoliday, action name is Index.

Comment: You can call a view in MVC. MVC works by calling action methods in controllers that return a view.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, But I solved my problem by writing the below route.          routes.MapRoute(
                null,
                "Operations/BankHolidays.aspx",
                new { Controller = "BankHoliday", action = "Index" }
                );

Comment: Which will call the `Index()` method of `BankHolidayController` as I noted above (not an _aspx page_) :)